# Smoke Render Not showing Smoke but the Flow Source(Particle System)

Tags: rendering

When I render the smoke simulation all I see is the particles not the smoke itself.

The Way I want it.
[image]

[image]

The Way I see it when I render.

Answer (score 1):

You need to uncheck emitter in the render panel of the particle system.

[image: Emitter]

Comment: Nothing Changed.